# Apple Mach-O Linker Warning with libxml2

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings, libxml2

In xcode4.6 I added the libxml2 liberary and edited the "Other Linker Flags" with -lxml2 and "(User) Head Search Paths" with /usr/include/libxml2 and  now I get this warning:
http://i46.tinypic.com/91icjm.png

Does somebody know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Xcode IDE and a normal Xcode project, adding -lxml2 to the linker flags is not the best way to link with it. You're much better off to add it to the project as follows:

1. Click on the project (the topmost node in file browser)
2. In Build Phases, under “Link Binary With Libraries”, click the +. You'll get a list of dylibs and frameworks you can link with.
3. Select libxml2.dylib out of the list.

Works fine for my Mac project on Xcode 4.5.2.

Comment: Yes, I have also added the libxml2.dylib in the "Link Binary With Labraries" section... I've done both.

Comment: You should only do the “Link Binary With Libraries”. You should not also do -lxml2 at the same time.